# Magento cancel onhold orders

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

Is there any possibility to `cancel` the on hold orders **magento1.9** soap **API**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only cancel an order if the status is **Pending**.

If to be done using SOAP API, your path of request would be:

```
SOAP v1: sales_order.unhold > sales_order.cancel
SOAP v2: salesOrderUnhold > salesOrderCancel
```

Both methods needs `sessionId` and `orderIncrementId` as arguments to be supplied in your request.